# Why RenderBody() not working inside code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razorengine

Why in a ASP.NET MVC Razor Layout Page

```
@if (true)
{
    <div>@RenderBody()</div>
}
```

**works**, However the code below **does not**?

```
@if (true)
{
    RenderBody();
}
```

If will execute the codes that RenderBody() suppose to render, but output nothing in the final result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
@if (true)
{
  @RenderBody();
}
```

Comment: damn, you are right, I already get used to avoid @ inside @. And we do not need ; at end.

Comment: Ya, Razor syntax can confuse the heck out of you at times.  I've been there many times.